# Projective varieties of dimension $m$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, holomorphic-functions

Let $X \subset \mathbb{CP}^n$ be a projective variety of dimension $m$. Is it true that $X$ can be realized as the image of a holomorphic map $f: \mathbb{CP}^m \to \mathbb{CP}^n$?

To this end, if there is a non-constant map $f: \mathbb{CP}^m \to X$ then it must be a surjection. This follows by the open mapping theorem together with compactness of $\mathbb{CP}^m$ and connectedness of the target. The thing that is unclear to me is whether or not one can always construct a non-constant holomorphic function from $\mathbb{CP}^m$ to an arbitrary projective variety.

Comment: You asked this a few days ago, no? I had added a comment asking you what happens in the case of curves, in particular the simplest case, that of elliptic curves. Did you think about that?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes I did see your comment! Unfortunately I got stuck trying to write down specific maps by hand rather than thinking about things like Riemann-Hurwitz. Of course now I understand that there can be no non-constant meromorphic maps from a curve of lower genus to a curve of higher genus.

The source of my confusion was this: Say I take a degree 3 map from CP^1 to CP^2 and look at its image. I had previously assumed that the use of the word “degree” here would indicate the image would be some projective curve of degree 3 (genus 1), but this is evidently not the case.

Comment: I suppose the deeper cause of my confusion is forgetting that degree is not an intrinsic concept. Take a rational normal curve in P^d, which can be written as the image of a map P^1 -> P^d. The degree of this curve is certainly d, but its genus is not given by the usual formula 2g = (d-1)(d-2) because the curve is not being realized in P^2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One situation where this is impossible is when $X \subset \mathbb{CP}^2$ is a elliptic curve (i.e. a smooth complex projective curve of genus 1, realisable as a cubic hypersurface in $\mathbb{CP}^2$).

If there exists a surjective map $f : \mathbb{CP}^1 \to X$, then by the [Riemann-Hurwitz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula), we would have
$$ 2g(\mathbb{CP}^1) - 2 = N (2g(X) - 2) + \sum_{P \in \mathbb{CP}^1} (e_P-1),$$
where $N$ is the degree of the covering map $f : \mathbb{CP}^1 \to X$, and for each $P \in \mathbb {CP}^1$, $e_P$ is the ramification index of $f$ at $P$ (which is greater than one at only finitely many $P \in \mathbb{CP}^1$).

Now, $g(\mathbb {CP}^1) = 0$, and $g(X) = 1$, so the left-hand side is negative, while the right-hand side is non-negative. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is smooth and not the projective space itself, then this is impossible by the following:

**Theorem** [[Lazarsfeld](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~roblaz/Reprints/Lazarsfeld.Applications.of.Pos.VBs.pdf), Thm. 4.1]**.** *Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective variety of dimension $m$. Assume that there is a surjective morphism $\mathbf{P}^m \to X$. Then, $X \cong \mathbf{P}^m$.*

There is also a version in positive characteristic, when the morphism is assumed to also be separable; see [[Kollár](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-03276-3), Cor. V.3.5].

On the other hand, you can have singular $X$ that admit surjective morphisms from $\mathbf{P}^m$ by taking the quotient of $\mathbf{P}^m$ by a finite group.